# How to add credential fields without using firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() in Android studio(java)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add name, email and password to firebase instead of using
  `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` in Android studio(java)?

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

               //java code

}
```

Comment: can you tell us why you don't want to use that method for account creation?

Comment: that method accepts only email and password to store it in firebase, I need user name also to be added so

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my code:**

**create user method:**

```
 if (validation()) {
                     String Email=mEdtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                     String UserName=mEdtUserName.getText().toString().trim();
                     String Password=mEdtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                     String ProfilePicture;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if(!profilepicurl.equals("")){
                         ProfilePicture=profilepicurl;
                    }
                    else{
                         ProfilePicture=null;
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUserId)) {
                        createUser(Email, UserName,Password,ProfilePicture);
                    }
                } else {
                    Common.displayToast(SignUpActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorWrong));
                }
```

**check validation:**

```
 private boolean validation() {
        if (!Validation.checkBlankValidation(mEdtEmail)) {
            mEdtEmail.requestFocus();
            Common.displayToast(SignUpActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorEmail));
            return false;
        } else if (!Validation.checkBlankValidation(mEdtUserName)) {
            mEdtUserName.requestFocus();
            Common.displayToast(SignUpActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorUserName));
            return false;
        } else if (!Validation.checkPasswordValidation(mEdtPassword)) {
            mEdtPassword.requestFocus();
            Common.displayToast(SignUpActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.strErrorPassword));
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**java code:**

```
   private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
   private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

   mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Your Node Name");

     private void createUser(String UserName, String email, String password,String ProfilePicture) {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUserId)) {
                mUserId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
                Log.e(TAG, "++mUserId" + mUserId);
            }

            InstaUser instaUser = new InstaUser(mUserId,UserName, email, password,ProfilePicture);
            mFirebaseDatabase.child(mUserId).setValue(instaUser);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Common.displayToast(SignUpActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.strSucess));
            Common.passIntent(SignUpActivity.this, DashBoardFeedActivity.class);
            finish();
        }
```

**model class:**

```
/**
 * Created by rucha
 */

public class InstaUser {

    public String userid;
    public String email;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String profilepicurl;

    // Default constructor required for calls to
    // DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    public InstaUser() {
    }

    public InstaUser(String userid,String email, String username, String password, String profilepicurl) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password=password;
        this.profilepicurl=profilepicurl;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getProfilepicurl() {
        return profilepicurl;
    }

    public void setProfilepicurl(String profilepicurl) {
        this.profilepicurl = profilepicurl;
    }
}
```

This is work perfectly for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

let me know if you have any issues!!

happy to help!! :)

Comment: Thank you Rucha, I'll let u know if it works for me:)